# Retrospectively Minimum Business Days from today till the next date in another column for different Codes

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I just am unable to solve this without applying loops and I have pretty long data of timeseries. I want to know what is the closest next maturity date based on information we know today. Example below: Note the next expiry date should be for that specific code. There has got to be a more pythonic way of doing this.

`date          matdate   code
2-Jan-2018   5-Jan-2018     A
3-Jan-2018   6-Jan-2018     A
8-Jan-2018   12-Jan-2018    B
10-Jan-2018  15-Jan-2018    A
11-Jan-2018  16-Jan-2018    B
15-Jan-2018  17-Jan-2018    A`

And I am looking for the output to be in the below format - which takes all weekday dates in the output (the below could also be in pivot format, but should have all weekday dates as index)

`date          matdate   code   BusinessDaysToNextMat
2-Jan-2018   5-Jan-2018     A              3
2-Jan 2018                  B              0
3-Jan-2018   8-Jan-2018     A              2
3-Jan-2018                  B              0
4-Jan-2018                  A              1
4-Jan-2018                  B              0
5-Jan-2018                  A              0
5-Jan-2018                  B              0
8-Jan-2018                  A              0
8-Jan-2018   17-Jan-2018    B              7
9-Jan-2018                  A              0
9-Jan-2018                  B              6
10-Jan-2018  16-Jan-2018    A              4
10-Jan-2018                 B              6
11-Jan-2018                 A              3
11-Jan-2018  16-Jan-2018    B              3
12-Jan-2018                 A              4
12-Jan-2018                 B              2
15-Jan-2018  17-Jan-2018    A              1
15-Jan-2018                 B              1`

Thank you very much for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.busday_count](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) to achieve that:
    import numpy as np

```
df['BusinessDaysToNextMat'] = df[['date', 'matdate']].apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(*x), axis=1)
df

#        date    matdate code  BusinessDaysToNextMat
#0 2018-01-01 2018-01-05    A                      4
#1 2018-01-03 2018-01-06    A                      3
#2 2018-01-08 2018-01-12    B                      4
#3 2018-01-10 2018-01-15    A                      3
#4 2018-01-11 2018-01-16    B                      3
#5 2018-01-15 2018-01-17    A                      2
#6 2018-01-20 2018-01-22    A                      0
```

This doesn't seem completely what you had in your example, but does the most:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [pd.date_range(
                df['date'].min(),
                df['date'].max(), freq='C').values,
         df['code'].unique()],
                names = ['date', 'code'])

resampled = pd.DataFrame(index=index).reset_index().merge(df, on=['date', 'code'], how='left')

calc = resampled.dropna()
calc['BusinessDaysToNextMat'] = calc[['date', 'matdate']].apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(*x), axis=1)
final = resampled.merge(calc, on=['date', 'code', 'matdate'], how='left')
final['BusinessDaysToNextMat'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

final
#         date code    matdate  BusinessDaysToNextMat
#0  2018-01-02    A 2018-01-05                    3.0
#1  2018-01-02    B        NaT                    0.0
#2  2018-01-03    A 2018-01-06                    3.0
#3  2018-01-03    B        NaT                    0.0
#4  2018-01-04    A        NaT                    0.0
#5  2018-01-04    B        NaT                    0.0
#6  2018-01-05    A        NaT                    0.0
#7  2018-01-05    B        NaT                    0.0
#8  2018-01-08    A        NaT                    0.0
#9  2018-01-08    B 2018-01-12                    4.0
#10 2018-01-09    A        NaT                    0.0
#11 2018-01-09    B        NaT                    0.0
#12 2018-01-10    A 2018-01-15                    3.0
#13 2018-01-10    B        NaT                    0.0
#14 2018-01-11    A        NaT                    0.0
#15 2018-01-11    B 2018-01-16                    3.0
#16 2018-01-12    A        NaT                    0.0
#17 2018-01-12    B        NaT                    0.0
#18 2018-01-15    A 2018-01-17                    2.0
#19 2018-01-15    B        NaT                    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for he quick response - apols I just edited it a bit - let me check if your response still holds..

Comment: @spiff well it solves the numbers but your new output is much different than the last one.

Comment: Ah - so your solution may not work as the next closest mat date could on a trade done in the past well?

Comment: So for eg in your #1 entry, th enext date would be 5th (done on a trade in the past) and not 6th and so the business days would be just 2 and not 3

Comment: @spiff This would return negative value for that case.

Comment: indeed - hence need a solution which looks back

Comment: any thoughts mate?

Comment: @spiff Well I fixed for the formatting, but still not sure how your got some values.

Comment: Thanks again - i just posted what I am doing currently - if that helps understand the problem better maybe?

Answer (score 0):

here is what I am doing currently, which clearly isn't most efficient:

```
# Step1: Make a new df with data of just one code and fill up any blank matdates with the very first available matdate. After that:
temp_df['newmatdate'] = datetime.date(2014,1,1) # create a temp column to hold the current minimum maturity date
temp_df['BusinessDaysToNextMat'] = 0 # this is the column that we are after

mindates = [] # initiate a list to maintain any new maturity dates which come up and keep it min-sorted
mindates.append(dummy) # where dummy is the very first available maturity date (as of 1st date we only know one trade, which is this) Have written dummy here, but it is a longer code, which may not pertain here
x = mindates[0] # create a variable to be used in the loop

g = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(len(temp_df['matdate'])): # loop through every date
    if np.in1d(temp_df['matdate'][i],mindates)[0]==False: # if the current maturity date found DOES NOT exist in the list of mindates, add it
        mindates.append(temp_df['matdate'][i])
    while min(mindates)< temp_df['date'][i]: # if the current date is greater than the min mindate held so far, 
        mindates.sort() # sort it so you are sure to remove the min mindate
        x = mindates[0] # note the date which you are dropping before dropping it
        del mindates[0] # drop the curr min mindate, so the next mindate, becomes the new min mindate
    if temp_df['matdate'][i] != x: # I think this might be redundant, but it is basically checking if the new matdate which you may be adding, wasn't the one
        mindates.append(temp_df['matdate'][i]) # which you just removed, if not, add this new one to the list
    curr_min = min(mindates)
    temp_df['newmatdate'][i] = curr_min # add the current min mindate to the column

h = datetime.datetime.now()
print('loop took '+str((h-g).seconds) + ' seconds')

date = [d.date() for d in temp_df['date']] # convert from 'date' to 'datetime' to be able to use np.busday_count()
newmatdate = [d.date() for d in temp_df['newmatdate']]
temp_df['BusinessDaysToNextMat'] = np.busday_count(date,newmatdate) # phew
```

Also this is just for a single code - and then i will loop it over as many codes there are